# Simplify if-elseif conditional

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a hole class with properties x,y,w,h,id and in order to differentiate between them (like a sort)
I have these conditions.

While this works, I can imagine there to be a simpler way to write it. (Without nested if statements?)
ps: height and minHeight are just other variables independant of the hole

```cpp
// Differentiate holes with equal properties to get a deterministic result

if (height < minHeight) return true;
else if (height == minHeight)
{
    if (hole->x < bestHole->x) return true;
    else if (hole->x == bestHole->x)
    {
        if (hole->y < bestHole->y) return true;
        else if (hole->y == bestHole->y)
        {
            if (hole->h < bestHole->h) return true;
            else if (hole->h == bestHole->h)
            {
                if (hole->w < bestHole->w) return true;
                else if (hole->w == bestHole->w)
                {
                    if (hole->id < bestHole->id) return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

I tried to simplify knowing that: if (a) if (b) return c;
is the same as: if (a && b) return c;
only to not find the same result.

No relation between question and 'associated question'
The associated question is about classes and std containers whereas this question is about conditions????

Comment: are you trying to do something like `hole1 < hole2` ?

Comment: Yes, like a comparator function for sort(), however when i just do `if (height < minHeight) return true; else return false;` I get non-deterministic results

Comment: You may want to use std::tie() search for std::tie less

Comment: ***No relation between question and 'associated question' The associated question is about classes and std containers whereas this question is about conditions????*** The duplicate is definitely the  solution to your problem.

Comment: How is simplification of a conditional statement in any way related to std containers and operator <>

Comment: Because the simplicification you want is the same solution.  You want to get rid of the if/else ifs.  You do that by leveraging `std::tuple` using `std::tie` and do `std::tie(all, of, the, things, to, check) < std::tie(other, objects, members, to, compare, against)`

Comment: Just use std::tie to simplify your if () statements.